# Pulling db secrets from vault to execute Jooq not working on localhost

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq, hashicorp-vault

We are using `jooq` to generate the code to query our db. For `jooq` to run we provide the configuration using environment variables like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
        <jdbc>
            <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
            <url>${DB_URL}</url>
            <user>${DB_USER}</user>
            <password>${DB_PASSWORD}</password>
        </jdbc>

        <generator>
            <name>org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator</name>

            <database>
                <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                <includes>.*</includes>
                <excludes />
                <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
                <inputSchema>myDb</inputSchema>
            </database>

            <generate>
                <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
            </generate>

            <target>
                <packageName>com.myapp.jooq</packageName>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq-postgres</directory>
            </target>
        </generator>
    </configuration>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

In order to set these properties `DB_URL`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` we use `vault-maven-plugin` that is executed before jooq in maven lifecycle. This is the configuration we use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.deciphernow</groupId>
    <artifactId>vault-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pull</id>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>pull</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <servers>
                    <server>
                        <url>http://my.hostedvault.net:8200</url>
                        <token>myTokenHere</token>
                        <paths>
                            <path>
                                <name>secret/myApp</name>
                                <mappings>
                                    <mapping>
                                        <key>spring.datasource.username</key>
                                        <property>DB_USER</property>
                                    </mapping>
                                    <mapping>
                                        <key>spring.datasource.password</key>
                                        <property>DB_PASSWORD</property>
                                    </mapping>
                                    <mapping>
                                        <key>spring.datasource.url</key>
                                        <property>DB_URL</property>
                                    </mapping>
                                </mappings>
                            </path>
                        </paths>
                    </server>
                </servers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is working perfectly well, however when we change the plugin to `localhost:8200` it always return `404` error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.deciphernow:vault-maven-plugin:1.0.0:pull (pull) on project myApp: Exception thrown pulling secrets. Vault responded with HTTP status code: 404 -> [Help 1]

This only happens for localhost vault used in the `vault-maven-plugin`. So, this looks like a bug on the maven plugin (I confirmed my localhost vault works property and spring-boot can pull from it without problems). Any idea how I can provide Jooq with credentials properties stored in vault?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, so posting the answer in case it helps another one with the same problem.

I was running `vault` in `dev` mode, so when we use this mode vault is appending `/data` to the uri. I had started vault this way:

```
docker run -p 8200:8200 --name='vault' --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -e 'VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=myroottoken' vault
```

The plugin `vault-maven-plugin` seems to work with `vault` running in `server` (production) mode. So, if we start vault with this command everything works fine:

```
docker container run --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h", "ui": "true", "listener": {"tcp": {"address": "0.0.0.0:8200", "tls_disable": "true"}}}' -e VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200 -e VAULT_API_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200 -p 8200:8200 vault server
```

Beware that you must unseal vault by entering in the container with:

```
docker container exec -it <containerId> /bin/sh
```

And issue this command: `vault operator init`